# Using WP REST API WordPress plugin to add posts to my PHP page

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I am redoing my personal website and wanted to add a section for recent posts from wordpress. This way I can have 3 posts on my main index page that I can just update with phone without having to code new things in. I installed the WordPress plugin WP REST API. I even checked it by using the domainname/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ and it is showing the four test posts I have created.

I don't really know anything about JSON API but I am having the hardest time trying to acquire those recent posts into my featured posts section. I have been scavenging the internet in hopes of a tutorial that would help me but nothing is really showing the post on my page. Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are general pointers based on your question:

First, you need to get the posts from WP from `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/`. For that, you need to do a `curl` GET request.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://codular.com/curl-with-php), replace the example domain with your site when making request in your PHP page.

The result will be a JSON object. Now, do a `json_decode()` on the result and you should have an array or object. You can display the results by iterating over it.

Here's an example displaying all the headlines:

```
    <section id="blog">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                FEATURED POSTS
                <?php
                    // Get cURL resource
                    $curl = curl_init();
                    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
                    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.bmcsquincy.com/featured_posts/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/',
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
                    ));
                    // Send the request & save response to $resp
                    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
                    // Close request to clear up some resources
                    curl_close($curl);

                    $resp=json_decode($resp, TRUE);
                    //var_dump($resp);

                    foreach($resp as $post) {
                        echo '<h2>' . $post['title']['rendered'] . '</h2><br />';
                    }
                ?>
            </div><!--END ROW-->
        </div><!--END CONTAINER FLUID-->
</section><!--END SECTION BLOG-->
```

Comment: okay I tried to set up a curl. I can not get it to show anything. i showed my code up in a new answer above

Comment: @Digital_Jedi_3  Remove the `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` from the options array. You are making a POST request, you should make GET request. I've updated the question with demo code.

Comment: Sharama - Awesome! Thank you I guess I will be reading up on this once completed to learn more about these amazing capabilities! Couple of questions that I have... The title is now showing but I cannot make it link to the blog. I tried - echo '<strong><a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title->rendered.'</a></strong>'; and it doesn't work. Also I was wondering if I can show about 50 words or so of what the blog is about and have a featured image? Doing this will be almost exactly what I am looking for! Again thanks for your response and all help you have given!

Comment: When you tried linking to blog, did line 97 above say `$resp=json_decode($resp);` or `$resp=json_decode($resp, true);`? If it was like first one, then it should work. Else, you need to write `$post['link']` and `$post['title']['rendered']`.

Comment: Here's some rough code with blog title, description: https://gist.github.com/ishansharma/fd8068ba74b4ccef97cb040e3f442000

Featured media is a bit more complicated, you will have to grab `$post['_links']['wp:featuredmedia']['href']` and make a curl request to this URL and read `['source_url']` from this response.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.bmcsquincy.com/featured_posts/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ and this is how i know that part is working.

for the php i used

```
    <section id="blog">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                FEATURED POSTS
                <?php
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.bmcsquincy.com/featured_posts/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        item1 => 'value',
        item2 => 'value2'
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
?>
            </div><!--END ROW-->
        </div><!--END CONTAINER FLUID-->
</section><!--END SECTION BLOG-->
```